# Terraform EC2 userdata not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "FWInstance" {
  disable_api_termination = false
  iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.FirewallBootstrapInstanceProfile2Tier.name}"
  instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = "stop"
  ebs_optimized = true
  ami = "${var.PANFWRegionMap[var.aws_region]}"
  instance_type = "m4.xlarge"

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_size = 60
  }

  key_name = "${var.ServerKeyName}"
  monitoring = false

  network_interface {
    device_index = 0
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.FWManagementNetworkInterface.id}"
  }

  user_data = "${base64encode(join("", list("vmseries-bootstrap-aws-s3bucket=", var.MasterS3Bucket)))}"
}
```

When running it through terraform it creates the instance but stops at VM login and never runs the user_data code.

I tried using remote_exec like this:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["# Connected!"]
  }
```

It waits for 5 min. and errors out as instance is not created by that time.

Is there a way to run user data in this ec2 instance through terraform? When I create a similar instance in AWS without terraform it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs on the instance to see why the userdata did not run?

If your `remote-exec` provisioner didn't connect, then you are likely looking at a firewall issue or a misconfiguration.

You don't provide any error messages or any information of what type of OS you are running, which makes it hard to help you. For example, different OS like Windows, Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, and Container Linux parse userdata differently.

Try running Terraform with debugging output. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not pass base64 encoded data to `user_data`, as Terraform will base64 encode it for you. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data

If you must pass in base64 encoded data, use `user_data_base64` instead.

Change your code to:

```
  user_data = "${join("", list("vmseries-bootstrap-aws-s3bucket=", var.MasterS3Bucket))}"
```

Comment: FYI - Anytime your user-data doesn't seem to be running, your first step should be to check that the user-data is being passed in to AWS correctly. You can do this by running `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data` on the instance or by selecting the instance in the console and viewing its userdata.

The next step is to check the logs on the instance to look for execution errors.

Comment: It is Linux AMI from PaloAlto. Above code still, doesnt work. I will try debug now.

Comment: It won't change the result, but your code could be simplified to `user_data = "vmseries-bootstrap-aws-s3bucket=${var.MasterS3Bucket}"`

Comment: I figured it out kind off. If I remove the network interface, it works. Any idea why?

Comment: Possibilities: your security group rules on the ENI aren't correct or perhaps an ENI attached at index 0 prevents access to the metadata endpoint. It's hard to troubleshoot without knowing the details of the failure.